# Djangoで作成したAPIでGETしたJSONデータを実機のTableViewに反映させたい

Tags: swift, ios, json, django, alamofire

以下のjsonデータが返ってくるURLは　http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/　です
シミュレータ上では正しくレスポンスが取得できましたが，実機で試みたところ，取得できませんでした．どうすれば良いでしょうか？
使用しているのはAlamofire4.0です．

JSON

```
{
"books": [
{
  "id": 1, 
  "name": "Django入門", 
  "publisher": "GeekLab Nagano", 
  "page": 10, 
  "impressions": [
    {
      "id": 1, 
      "comment": "途中で\r\n眠くなった。"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2, 
      "comment": "ああ"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 3, 
      "comment": "いい"
    }
  ]
}, 
{
  "id": 2, 
  "name": "Raspberry Pi 入門", 
  "publisher": "GeekLab Nagano", 
  "page": 15, 
  "impressions": []
}
]
}
```

コード

```
var tableTitle = [String]()
var tableDetail = [String]()
let url:String = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/"

func loadData() {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {
        response in

        guard let value = response.result.value else {
            return
        }
        let json = JSON(value)
        let books = json["books"]

        for item in books.arrayValue {
            self.tableTitle.append(item["name"].stringValue)
            self.tableDetail.append(item["publisher"].stringValue)
        }

        print(self.tableTitle)
        print(self.tableDetail)


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: サーバー側のレスポンスヘッダで`Content-Type`を`application/json`にしていますか？であればサーバー側(Django)の処理に問題はなさそうなので、タイトルを「AlamofireでJSONのレスポンスが取得できない」などに変更したほうが回答を得られやすくなると思います。

Comment: 説明不足ですいません．実機でTableViewに表示しようと試みていましたが，シミュレータ上で実行してみたら表示されました．理由はローカルホストにつなげていたからでした．実機でレスポンス取得するにはリモートでサーバを立ち上げる必要がありそうです．

Answer (score 1):

Djangoを実行する時のデフォルトのホストである`127.0.0.1`だとDjangoを実行したマシンからしかアクセスできませんので、以下の様に起動して下さい。

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

これで同じネットワーク上の他のマシンから`http://<Djangoを実行しているマシン名またはIPアドレス>:8000/`でアクセスできるようになります。

#### 追記

> シミュレータ上では正しくレスポンスが取得できましたが，実機で試みたところ，取得できませんでした．どうすれば良いでしょうか？

「取得できませんでした」だとどういう状況かわかりません。
HTTPリクエストでうまくいかない状況としては

- サーバーに接続できない
- サーバーからレスポンスは返ってくるけどHTTPステータスコードがエラー(500など)になっている
- サーバーからのレスポンスでコンテンツ(今回でいうとJSONデータ)が正しく取得できない

などがあります。

これらのどこでうまくいっていないかによって、原因と対応方法は変わってきます。
自分はSwingはわからないので具体的にどう確認すればいいのかは書けませんが、HTTP通信をする際はこれらのどこでうまくいっていないかを確認することをお勧めします。

#### 追記2

Djangoの`settings.py`で接続を許可するホストを指定するための設定があります。
デフォルトだと

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

となっていてDjangoを実行しているマシンからしかアクセスできないので、どこからでもアクセスできるようにするには

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*]
```

として下さい。